# How do I make a piston elevator?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I always wanted to make a piston elevator to get to different levels quickly. How can I build an elevator?

Comment: I have a suggestion, you could use the teleporting feature of command blocks to get to different floors quickly.

Comment: What kind of elevator?  Water?  Piston?  I'd suggest looking at YouTube.

Comment: Piston and I don't want to mess with command blokes

Comment: Wanting specifically a *piston* elevator is an important detail. I've added it to the question.

Comment: @Awesomest_Donut There is currently no such thing as Command Blocks in Xbox or PS3 Edition, only for PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different types of elevators you can make, I would start by reading here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Elevators

My personal favorite? Water.